# Why Does Jupyter Notebook Crashes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, kernel, jupyter

I am using Python 2.7 on Windows 10 (64) computer. Whenever I work with Jupyter notebook, it dies for no reason. Sometimes it dies while I am using it, sometimes when it is idle. I receive below error messages.

Error message screenshot

[image: Error message screenshot]

When I check the command line, the error says:

> Assertion failed: Connection reset by peer (bundled\zeromq\src\signaler.cpp:181)

I'd appreciate any help on how to fix this problem. Thanks

Comment: got win10,  python2.7 64bit, anaconda distribution, never had that errror

Comment: It seems to be a [known](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9236) [problem](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/issues/1808). No solution as of yet, both issues are still open...

Comment: Do you think it is a 2.7 problem ?