# Jupyter notebook python crash on Windows 10

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, jupyter, pyzmq

I have spent a week searching and trying different solutions with no luck. I've seen several others having the same problems going back over a year.

**The issue:**

Windows 10 Pro build 15063.674

I'm using the latest Anaconda 5 build with Python 3.6.2 and all the packages are updated to most recent.

Running Jupyter Notebook, after some time, python will crash with a dialog "python has stopped working". This seems to happen after the notebook has been open for awhile, but I haven't been able to pinpoint an exact time. It's longer than 15 minutes but I've had it crash after a couple hours too.

The crash happens whether or not the notebook is in use, but most of the time, it's been while it's idle.

The console contains several lines like this:

```
Assertion failed: Connection reset by peer (bundled\zeromq\src\signaler.cpp:298)
```

I had been using everything with no issues, on a daily basis for months prior to this. I honestly have no idea what could have changed other than Windows Automatic updates.

**What I've tried:**

- updating anaconda
- updating all packages
- updating python
- full clean removal then reinstall of anaconda, python, and all packages
- updating everything again
- removing pyzmq and Jupyter then reinstalling
- disabling Windows Defender
- attempted to revert pyzmq on a long shot to 13.1.0 but the build failed
- I've also tried using both `conda` and `pip` for installing/removing

**Threads I've read:**

- https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/issues/1808
- https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9975
- https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9236
- https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/issues/1108
- https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/issues/1573
- [Why python raised an AssertionError on some failed assumption in a ZeroMQ client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37962472/why-python-raised-an-assertionerror-on-some-failed-assumption-in-a-zeromq-client)
- [Python.exe crashes while running Jupyter notebook sever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39304869/python-exe-crashes-while-running-jupyter-notebook-sever)
- [Why Does Jupyter Notebook Crashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083950/why-does-jupyter-notebook-crashes)

Any suggestions on fixing this?

Comment: Just an educated guess: have you tried disabling any firewall and other system protection software? While this should obviously only be done when not connected to the internet, it might still be worth checking because terminating lingering network connections might be related to this.

Comment: do you have EMET running on your win10 machine? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Mitigation_Experience_Toolkit

Comment: @denfromufa I haven't installed it and I don't see it on my system, but I am running Windows 10 build 15063.674

Comment: I have this problem in win7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to uninstall a program called Networx.

I don't understand the error myself but the person I got the solution from linked this post: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1554#issuecomment-339743927

Comment: If i am not wrong, NetworkX is that cool library which lets you work with graphs. Why would it cause this problem? It works fine on my machine.

Comment: I have uninstall the newworkX, and the crash still appears

Answer (score 0):

From the [first issue thread you linked](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/issues/1808), it looks like this issue is with ZeroMQ, with little hope for resolution. One poster (UniversalAE) in that thread seemed to have success with replacing ZeroMQ with RabbitMQ. Absent an update to ZeroMQ that resolves this, or any specific requirement for ZeroMQ, I would advise doing the same, i.e. swap out ZeroMQ for RabbitMQ.