# python crashes while running jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

i have installed Anaconda on my machine. In anaconda terminal python working properly but when I run jupyter notebook or spyder python crashes with following error message:

**The exception unknown software exception(0x40000015) occurred in the application at location oxfcdbaa7d**

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: python.exe
  Application Version:  3.6.10150.1013
  Application Timestamp:    5eb4c8bb
  Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7600.16385
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4a5bdfe0
  Exception Code:   40000015
  Exception Offset: 000000000000aa7d
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 389b
  Additional Information 2: 389bb461874f8b25850c900f8e8bed17
  Additional Information 3: ef28
  Additional Information 4: ef2897a45abdb10847ea1ff86dcfeb5c
```

What i have tried:

windows and anaconda versions are same
reinstalling anaconda in the c drive
deleting previous python version
troubleshooting jupyter
links present in this article [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46623548/jupyter-notebook-python-crash-on-windows-10)

running on a different browser and almost everything present on google.

Please help I don't know what should i do next.

Comment: Can you include any code that might cause the problem?

Comment: When I open jupyter and choose python3 new notebook it opens in new tab and shows error message that python stops working. Thank You.

Comment: Python runs fine in Vs code but don't know what is the problem with jupyter notebook and Spyder.

Answer (score 0):

What browser did you use? Try Google chrome if you have not tried with it.